# UITableView reloadData blocks UI with many updates per second

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have an app that has the ability to download certain files. These files are shown in a `UITableView`, and when tapped, they begin to download.

I would like to show the progress of the downloads in the cell (for example, as a percentage). My code currently fires notifications when the download progress is updated.

The problem is that these progress updates are fired many (hundreds?) times per second. If I use `[tableView reloadData]`, or even `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:...]`, the UI lags like crazy once the download starts, because this is being called so frequently.

My code is very minimal other than this. I'm not using any uncommon UITableView delegate methods, and I've tried to eliminate everything other than updating the 'download' label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - but it still lags a lot!

What are my options? I could potentially create a timer that updates the UI every second or so in order to show download progress, but this seems hacky. The UI could be so much better! Is there ***any*** way that I can have my download label update instantly without lagging my UI?

Comment: Well it's much more better to refresh just the exact view, progressbar view whatever it is than the full tableview. In your case i would add that specific view as an observer of your notification, however you'll have to correctly set up the data, remove observers and so on while scrolling/loading new cells in your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to slow down the flow of notifications.

Assuming progress is between 0 and 1, in the method that fires the notification, use something similar to:

```
if (floorf(progress*100) == progress*100) {
  // send notification
}
```

This would only send a notification to refresh the cell when the progress if 1%, 2% etc.

In addition, in the UITableView, try to only reload visible cells:

```
if ([[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath:@[ indexPath ]];
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a potential solution. However, if multiple downloads are started, progress updates may still be sent many times per second from many different files.

Comment: even when using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:?

Comment: I'm talking about when the notification is fired, as you suggested. If I add your code to slow the frequency of notifications, that will work for each download. However, it is possible to download multiple files at once, which each send separate notifications. That means that although the number of notifications overall is dramatically reduced, it may still lag the UI.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I have already implemented this. It doesn't seem to make a substantial difference whether or not the whole table (`reloadData`) or just the individual rows are reloaded.

Comment: @ev0lution it probably doesn't make a difference because the rate of notifications is still very high. First cut down the rate of notifications. Then if more than the number of visible cells are updated, my last edit should help (with the `if` block checking the cells are visible before trying to update)

Comment: I've given it a shot and it actually works quite well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay method, which would look something like this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateCell:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.5];
```

The updateCell method would look something like this

```
- (void)updateCell:(CustomUITableViewCell *)cell {
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    if (cell && cell.downloadPercentage < 100) {
        [self updateCell:cell];
    }
}
```

What this is doing is calling the updateCell method every 1/2 second until the download is complete. It calls [cell setNeedsLayout] (or you could call whatever method you want to update your cell's display to update the percentage bar, like [cell setNeedsDisplay] or [cell updateDownloadLabel]) to update the cell, then calls updateCell again.

You can play around with the delay to get it looking and feeling how you want and balance performance.

There may be some issue with this getting called after a cell is scrolled off the screen, so make sure to check the cell still exists

Comment: `setNeedsLayout` does not cause `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called, which is where the text label is updated. How were you intending this to work? Also, what benefit does `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` have over simply calling the function directly? Your code also goes into an infinite loop after the first `updateCell:` call is made.

Comment: Replace setNeedsLayout for reloadRowAtIndexPath or whatever else method you want to reload your cell. The advantage to that method is that you get to perform it on a delay, which will increase performance since you are not constantly doing it. It does not go into an infinite loop if cell.downloadPercentage >= 100

Comment: Progress updates are being sent hundreds of times per second. It will delay them all by half a second, so that after half a second, they will start being sent hundreds of times per second again. If this is on the main thread, cell.downloadPercentage will never be able to be updated because you're constantly calling `updateCell:` - an infinite loop.

Comment: I would change the code you use to fire notification to do it at the right frequency for the UI to look smooth. If you add some of the code maybe I can help